# thrift : Unable to get a generator for "python"

Tags: java, python, thrift

I have thrift installed on my machine (Ubuntu 12.04).The version of thrift that I am using is 0.9.0.I have tried to generate python file for a thrift interface file as follows

```
thrift -gen python example.thrift
```

I get the following error

```
[WARNING:generation:1] Unable to get a generator for "python".
```

Do I need to install any additional packages in order for thrift to be able to generate python files.I am able to generate java file using thrift.

Comment: did you run `./configure --with-python=no` or something like this while installing thrift 0.9?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try replacing the "python" with "py":

```
thrift -gen py example.thrift
```